# Apache ECharts Data Zooming

Tags: charts, apache-echarts

[image: This is how my chart is currently]

I want to zoom in such a way that the picture fits correctly. I don't want to display values till 0, but maybe till 18000 on the Y Axis so that chart can be seen well.

```js
option = {
            "toolbox": {
                        "feature": {
                        "dataZoom": {
                            "yAxisIndex": "true"
                        },
                        "brush": {
                            "type": ['lineX', 'clear']
                        }
                        }
                    },
            "xAxis": {
                "data": datelist
            },
            "yAxis": {},
            "series": [
                {
                "type": 'candlestick',
                "data": ohlclist
                }
            ]
            }
return(option)
```

Answer (score 2):

The scale can be set automatically, by setting the `scale` option from yAxis to `true`:

```
yAxis: {
  scale: true,
},
```

Sometimes autoscale won't behave exactly as you want, so you can set the scale manually using the `min` and `max` options from yAxis :

```
yAxis: {
  min: 15000,
  max: 20000
},
```

Note: The `scale` option won't work if `min` and `max` are set